# (FFMpeg) Split the video by size after conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, codec

I have a 5,000MB long video in *.mp4* format. I would like to split the video into segments by the size. For example, I set the size to 1,024,000KB, or simply 1,024MB, because I want it to be accurate. Could conversion process from *.mp4* to (E.g *.vob*) be done while splitting process is going on? I would like to change some settings like bitrate or audio codec.
Example:

> (Bitrate: 2600kbps, Audio codec: AAC)
>
> > Original_video.mp4  --- **5,000,000 KB**

Converted:

> (Bitrate: 2200kbps, Audio codec: AC3)
>
> > First_video.vob --- **1,024,000 KB**
> >     Second_video.vob --- **1,024,000 KB**
> >     Thrid_video.vob --- **1,024,000 KB**
> >     Fourth_video.vob --- **1,024,000 KB**
> >     Fifth_video.vob --- **~300,000 KB**
> >     Total --- **~4,400,000GB**